# Subquery in WHERE clause results in full table scan before qualification

Tags: oracle, subquery, sql-execution-plan

I've got the following query

```
SELECT LkPartProduct.PartID, LkPartProduct.ProductID
FROM LkPartProduct
WHERE LkPartProduct.PartID IN (SELECT WO.PartID FROM WO WHERE WO.WOID = 310000000001549881)
AND LkPartProduct.PartIsRetired = 0
AND LkPartProduct.ProductIsRetired = 0
```

When I run this query the execution plan shows it returns every single record in LkPartProduct (a view) before it then does a merge join

See:

| Id | Operation | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT |  | 33 | 1881 | 245M |
| 1 | MERGE JOIN |  | 33 | 1881 | 245M |
| 2 | VIEW |  | 7309K | 271M | 245M |
| 3 | WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK |  | 7309K | 118G | 245M |
| 4 | FILTER |  |  |  |  |

Full plan can be found here https://pastebin.com/raw/sCRBhZHS

If I change that query to filter on the PartID without a lookup the plan is much more sensible.

```
SELECT LkPartProduct.PartID, LkPartProduct.ProductID
FROM LkPartProduct
WHERE LkPartProduct.PartID IN (310101554)
AND LkPartProduct.PartIsRetired = 0
AND LkPartProduct.ProductIsRetired = 0
```

| Id | Operation | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT |  | 33 | 1287 | 1212 |
| 1 | VIEW |  | 33 | 1287 | 1212 |
| 2 | WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK |  | 33 | 559K | 1212 |
| 3 | FILTER |  |  |  |  |

Full plan here https://pastebin.com/raw/fc08r1L1

I know it is comparing apples to oranges but the same query in MSSQL works without any problems, but in Oracle it seems it's always making a poor decision about how best to query the data. Logicall I expected the subquery to return the PartID and then this used in the filtering.

Any suggestions?

I've tried sticking the PartID into a Private Temp Table, a CTE, a JOIN instead but no joy.

As requested, here is the view

https://pastebin.com/raw/3n2qqV0Z

If I run the following to just get the PartID from the WO

```
SELECT WO.PARTID FROM WO WHERE WO.WOID = 310000000001549881
```

The explain plan is as follows

| Id | Operation | Name | E-Rows | E-Bytes | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT |  | 1 | 18 | 3 |
| 1 | TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | WO | 1 | 18 | 3 |
| 2 | INDEX RANGE SCAN | IM_WOID_ROUTINGID | 1 |  | 2 |

Running the following is fast as you might expect

```
SELECT LkPartProduct.PartID, LkPartProduct.ProductID
FROM LkPartProduct
WHERE LkPartProduct.PartID IN (select /*+ PRECOMPUTE_SUBQUERY */ WO.PartID FROM WO WHERE WO.WOID = 310000000001549881)
```

Explain for that here

https://pastebin.com/raw/MwtinW3e

Some details:

`WOID` is a `NUMBER(19)`

I have the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX I_CID ON WO(CUSTOMERID);
CREATE INDEX I_RFJSID ON WO(RFJOBSTATUSID);
CREATE INDEX I_WO_PARTID ON WO(PARTID);
CREATE INDEX I_WO_RUNNO ON WO(RUNNO, WOID, WONUMBER, PARTID);
CREATE INDEX I_WOREF ON WO(WOREFID);
CREATE INDEX I_WOROUTINGID ON WO(ROUTINGID);
CREATE INDEX IM_WOID_ROUTINGID ON WO(WOID, ROUTINGID);
```

Comment: Is the subquery expected to return exactly 1 row?  What happens if you replace `IN` with `=`?

Comment: Always use qualified names to be sure the field comes from the table you need. Maybe there's a column with the same name in filter table

Comment: @astentx I've updated so it's qualified in the question, that's me being lazy when typing it out.

Comment: @DaveCosta Changing to an = makes no difference either.

Comment: Can you post the definition of the view?  My guess is that there is something in the view definition that is preventing Oracle from pushing the predicate.

Comment: Can you also post the full plans (including the access and filter predicates and object names)?  The first step of both plans is a filter but one filter is presumably filtering out vastly more information and it's not obvious why.

Comment: Is table statistics collected? What is E-rows in the `WO` table access operation? Poor decision can be made because of poor estimates. The only thing can that can help here is to use `/+PRECOMPUTE_SUBQUERY*/` hint in filter subquery, if you really sure it will return a small number of rows. But as of now it is not documented.

Comment: In addition to request of full plan please use `dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'BASIC +IOSTATS +PREDICATE')` to get filter information and rowcounts.

Comment: @JustinCave Updated with the view and the full plans now.

Comment: What indexes do you have defined? What is the datatype of `WOID`?

Comment: Oracle is unable to push your predicate into the view, could be due to the computation and filter of `dense_rank`, could be due to the way you're filtering with all the `or`s, this looks like a more convoluted version of the conditional outer join antipattern. One trick to simplify how Oracle will deal with those `or`s is to wrap the whole filter up in one `case when` statement. Otherwise, the `precompute_subquery` hint will make the query get the literal values from your subquery, at the cost of parsing and being unsupported.

Comment: Just looking at the full explain plans, are you missing an index on LKPARTPRODUCTINNER mat view?  Or maybe the 2 queries that generated those explain plans are more different than the simplified queries posted here, not sure.

Comment: Hi @tbone Nope those are the queries that generated that explain plan. There is an index on LKPARTPRODUCTINNER

Comment: Hi @AndrewSayer do you mind explaining what you mean by wrapping up the whole filter into a single case when statement?

Comment: @Bohemian WOID is a NUMBER(19) ```CREATE INDEX SFOL.I_CID ON SFOL.WO
(CUSTOMERID)```, ```CREATE INDEX SFOL.I_RFJSID ON SFOL.WO
(RFJOBSTATUSID)```, ```CREATE INDEX SFOL.I_WO_PARTID ON SFOL.WO
(PARTID)``` , ```CREATE INDEX SFOL.I_WO_RUNNO ON SFOL.WO
(RUNNO, WOID, WONUMBER, PARTID)``` , ```CREATE INDEX SFOL.I_WOREF ON SFOL.WO (WOREFID)``` , ```CREATE INDEX SFOL.I_WOROUTINGID ON SFOL.WO (ROUTINGID)``` , ```CREATE INDEX SFOL.IM_WOID_ROUTINGID ON SFOL.WO (WOID, ROUTINGID)```

Comment: The query itself is very interesting. All second parts of `OR` can be replaced with `(Variant<N>TagList.RfTagListTypeID = 4 and TO_NUMBER(PartVariant1 DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) > Variant<N>TagListRange.MinValue and TO_NUMBER(PartVariant1 DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) <= Variant<N>TagListRange.MaxValue)` because otherwise you have inequality comparison of nulls, which returns undefined. It will be more easy to read

Comment: @astentx Thanks for that suggestion, I'll take a look at making those changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no index on `LkPartProduct.PartID`, so any lookup on it requires a full table scan.

Define one:

```
create index LkPartProduct_PartID_idx on LkPartProduct(PartID);
```

You have an index on `WO.WOID`, but it's a compound index on both `WOID` and `ROUTINGID`. you would improve performance a bit by creating one on just `WOID`:

```
create index WO_WOID_idx on WO(WOID);
```

Comment: LkPartProduct is a view (definition posted in main question), you can't have an index.

Comment: If you meant the LkPartProductInner, I've just added one there, previously I had just ```CREATE INDEX SFOL.IUM_PARTID_PRODUCTID_CUSTOMERID_CUSTOMERGROUPID_MACHINESTAGEID_PARTISRETIRED_PRODUCTISRETIRED ON SFOL.LKPARTPRODUCTINNER
(PRODUCTID, PARTID, CUSTOMERGROUPID, CUSTOMERID, MACHINESTAGEID, 
PARTISRETIRED, PRODUCTISRETIRED)```.

Comment: @BrandonBillingham Questions should be self-contained: Please delete the link to the view and put the view definition in your question.

Comment: the view is too large to put in the question

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why but doing this

```
SELECT LkPartProduct.PartID, LkPartProduct.ProductID
FROM LkPartProduct,
LATERAL (SELECT WO.PartID FROM WO WHERE WO.WOID = 310000000001549881 AND LkPartProduct.PartID = WO.PartID)
WHERE LkPartProduct.PartIsRetired = 0
AND LkPartProduct.ProductIsRetired = 0
```

Works great, but then now I've ran the above it's almost like Oracle has figured it out and the below is equally fast, exact same execution plan.

```
SELECT ProductID,
       PartID
FROM LkPartProduct
WHERE LkPartProduct.PartID IN (SELECT PartID FROM WO WHERE WOID = 310000000001549881)
AND LkPartProduct.PartIsRetired = 0
AND LkPartProduct.ProductIsRetired = 0
```

I then went and added in the index as suggested by @Bohemian and that has improved the performance from 876ms to 542ms.

Comment: Maybe because you've further restricted `PartIsRetired` and `ProductIsRetired` (which are present in index on `LKPARTPRODUCTINNER`), so index skip scan was costed lower than without this filter.

Comment: I missed them in my original question, but they were present in my tests.